# MVC Custom action route - 404 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

I want to use custom URL route:

```
http://localhost/MyController/MyView/11/25?someID=0
```

to do so, I have the following action:

```
[Route("{page}/{size}")]
public ActionResult MyView(int page = 0, int size = 25, FilterModel filterModel = null)
{
   ...
}
```

but I get the 404 error. What's wrong ? For example, that URL works:

```
http://localhost/MyController/MyView?someID=0
```

Answer (score 1):

The route you defined:

```
[Route("{page}/{size}")]
public ActionResult MyView(int page = 0, int size = 25, FilterModel filterModel = null)
{
   ...
}
```

Does not match the URL you want:

```
http://localhost/MyController/MyView/11/25?someID=0
```

You need to ensure they are the same (assuming you are not using a `RoutePrefix` attribute on the controller):

```
[Route("MyController/MyView/{page}/{size}")]
public ActionResult MyView(int page = 0, int size = 25, FilterModel filterModel = null)
{
   ...
}
```

The reason why the URL `http://localhost/MyController/MyView?someID=0` works is most likely that it is matching your `Default` route and passing the correct controller and action names to the framework to get to the action method.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Note also that you need to have `route.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` *before* your default route in order to enable attribute routing.

Answer (score 0):

This is attribute routing. Apologies on the last answer.

routes.MapRoute(
    name: “MyView”,
    url: “{page}/{size}”,
    defaults: new { controller = “MyController”, action = “MyView” },
    constraints: new { page= "", size="" }
);

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: just 404 not found